# How do I separate respective value from id of an element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an element:

```
input name="crd[69][qty]" id="crd[69][qty]" value="1" size="4" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12"
```

Ii had mentioned the name in array format to be use in background PHP, what I need to achieve is:

- When user clicks on this textbox , I should be able to retrieve only "69" from the id of the element which is `"crd[69][qty]"`. This id will be varying for different textboxes...

Is there any jQuery function to accomplish this?

Comment: how to you want to retrieve???

Comment: Try this in firebug `'crd[69][qty]'.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]`

Comment: sry the input tag was cut off when i saved it.. now its visible in the question.. i wan the result "69" if its id is crd[69][qty]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a regex expert but this should work:

```
$('input').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var parts = id.match(/\[([0-9]+)\]\[([a-z]+)\]/);
    alert(parts[1] + ' - ' + parts[2]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7jUHz/1/

Answer (score 0):

After retrieving full string, you can use [javascript RegExp's](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) exec method. As it's said

> If you want to retrieve the part of the string that was matched, call the exec() function of the RegExp object that you created, e.g.: mymatch = myregexp.exec("subject").